# Use of "dafür aber" in the given context

Tags: meaning, adverb

Here is a sentence:

> Er war groß und bullig und hatte fast keinen Hals, **dafür aber** einen sehr großen Schnurrbart.

This one is quite confusing to me because I thought that the so called da-adverbs have to be used in cases when the thing they're referring to has already been mentioned. Hence, "dafür" would mean something like "for that". But I do not understand the grammar behind this case in point.

Answer (score 4):

Using *dafür* to refer to something already mentioned is only one of several uses of this pronomial adverb. *Dafür* can also mean *anstatt dessen*/*stattdessen*, meaning *instead*/*in place* (see, e. g., [meaning 4. b) at the DWDS](https://www.dwds.de/wb/daf%C3%BCr#d-1-4-2)).

> Er war groß und bullig und hatte fast keinen Hals, *dafür aber* einen sehr großen Schnurrbart.
>
> <sub>(He was big and beefy and had almost no neck, *but instead* (he had) a very large mustache.)</sub>

Especially in everyday language, *dafür* occurs in this meaning more often than *anstatt dessen* or *stattdessen*, in my opinion.

Answer (score 2):

"Dafür" in the usage here and in Björns usage is not a Pronominaladverb, but a Konjunktionaladverb. Although they overlap, you can clearly see the distinction here:

> Ich möchte ins Kino, aber habe **dafür** keine Zeit. (Pro-Adverb)
> Ich möchte zwar nicht ins Kino, **dafür** aber in den Zoo. (Konjunktionaladverb)

You can tell because you have troubles combining a the junction with the Pro-Adverb, which is not at all a problem when you use it as a Konjunktionaladverb, as junction + Konjunktionaladverb is an easy combination to do.

Comment: Neither the [DWDS](https://www.dwds.de/wb/daf%C3%BCr), which I referenced in my answer, nor [Wiktionary](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/daf%C3%BCr) make the distinction you suggest, but both classify *dafür* as a *Pronominaladverb*.

Comment: @BjörnFriedrich Duden makes the distinction.